# Searching in datatable not working if using template

Tags: angular, primeng

I am using PrimeNG datatables [link](http://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/datatable/filter) by using the following code in my angular 2 application and everything is working fine except searching if i use template and anchor tag for any of the column(you can see the second column "Matter"). Its good with searching for all other columns but not searching in 2nd and 5th because we are using template in it. How we can implement searching on these columns?

```
<p-dataTable expandableRows="true" [value]="caseDocs" [rows]="5" [rowsPerPageOptions]="[5,10,20]" [paginator]="true" [globalFilter]="gb">
    <p-column field="ClientName" header="Client" [sortable]="true"></p-column>
    <p-column field="Matter" header="Matter" [sortable]="true">
        <template let-col let-casedoc="rowData" pTemplate="body">
            <a class="like" (click)="showMatterInfo(casedoc[col.field])" title="Download" data-toggle="modal">
                {{casedoc['MatterName']}}
            </a>&nbsp;
        </template>
    </p-column>
    <p-column field="Name" header="Document" [sortable]="true"></p-column>
    <p-column field="DocumentType" header="DocumentType" [sortable]="true"></p-column>
    <p-column field="DateAdded" header="DateAdded" [sortable]="true">
        <template let-col let-casedoc="rowData" pTemplate="body">
            {{utcToLocal(casedoc[col.field])}}
        </template>
    </p-column>
    <p-column field="DocumentId" styleClass="col-button" header="Actions">
        <template pTemplate="header">
        </template>
        <template let-col let-casedoc="rowData" pTemplate="body">
            <a class="like" (click)="downloadCaseDocInfo(casedoc[col.field])" title="Download" data-toggle="modal">
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-download-alt"></i>
            </a>&nbsp;
            <a class="like" (click)="showEditCaseDocModel(casedoc[col.field])" title="Edit" data-toggle="modal">
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i>
            </a>&nbsp;
            <a class="like" title="Delete" (click)="showDeleteCaseDoc(casedoc[col.field])" data-toggle="modal">
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i>
            </a>
        </template>
    </p-column>
</p-dataTable>
```

Comment: Maybe you can find an answer here: [prime-ng datatable: how to use Globalfilter with ng-template tag in p-column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43610356/prime-ng-datatable-how-to-use-globalfilter-with-ng-template-tag-in-p-column)